# Java, Unknown characters ﾝ □ Xml response

Tags: java, html, xml, encoding, utf-8

I am currently trying to extract from an Xml file (that is accessible via this address: http://mobilite.euroairport.com/services/getDepartureAirports?language=French) a list of airports.
My problem is that the 'Ü' that should appear in "DÜSSELDORF" is impossible to read (even Ie or firefox directly).
I obtain something like this: 
    D□SSELDORF or D SSELDORF or D?SSELDORF

The following is the code that I used to try to find the encoding of this file (n is the string that contain "DÜSSELDORF"):

```
        byte[] bytes = n.getBytes();            
        Log.w("tagtag", (char) bytes[0] + " "+(char) bytes[1]+" "+(char) bytes[2]);
        bytes = n.getBytes("ASCII");            
        Log.w("tagtag", (char) bytes[0] + " "+(char) bytes[1]+" "+(char) bytes[2]);
        bytes = n.getBytes("Cp1252");           
        Log.w("tagtag", (char) bytes[0] + " "+(char) bytes[1]+" "+(char) bytes[2]);
        bytes = n.getBytes("UTF-8");            
        Log.w("tagtag", (char) bytes[0] + " "+(char) bytes[1]+" "+(char) bytes[2]);
        bytes = n.getBytes("ISO8859_1");            
        Log.w("tagtag", (char) bytes[0] + " "+(char) bytes[1]+" "+(char) bytes[2]);
        bytes = n.getBytes("ISO8859_2");
```

And this is the result (in Logcat for android) :

```
        10-08 09:41:30.557: W/tagtag(1506): D □ ﾝ
        10-08 09:41:30.557: W/tagtag(1506): D ? S
        10-08 09:41:30.567: W/tagtag(1506): D ﾝ S
        10-08 09:41:30.567: W/tagtag(1506): D □ ﾝ
        10-08 09:41:30.577: W/tagtag(1506): D ﾝ S
        10-08 09:41:30.637: W/tagtag(1506): D ﾝ S
```

My question is: do I make a mistake while trying to read this string, or is it a problem due to the server?

Comment: Seems like an ecoding issue. I believe it could be useful to observe the related links ----->

Comment: On the provided link, it returns DSELLDORF for DUS? Apart from that I inspected the traffic with wireshark, and the server returns "Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8\r\n" which AFAIK means that the server is misconfigured

Comment: yes it return DSSELDORF. That's why i said that even the IE or firefox can't read it. About your advice Johan, I don't understand where you want me to look ?

Comment: Hmm.. yes, but DSSELDORF is not the same as *"something like this : D□SSELDORF or D SSELDORF or D?SSELDORF"*.  I think @linski  is right in that the file does not have any character for that letter, and the general Upper Case nature of the letters makes me think whoever designed the format was intending the field to be an unique and identifiable representation of an airport, rather than the correct name in the local text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitley server/ (data service) (misconfiguration issue) / bug.

Server returns this line in HTML/XML response:

```
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8\r\n
```

I just inspected byte dump of the xml, this is how wireshark represents "DSSELDORF":

```
D..SSELDORF
```

in hex dump (see [UTF-8 code table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) for hex value c2 9d):

```
44 c2 9d 53 53
```

which would be:

```
44 - D
53 - S
```

and 
    C2 9D

gets interpreted as control character which is also known as non printable character - hence the "missing" U - which also explains your logcat output.

Comment: Thanks guy ! it was exactly what I guessed but I don't know much about servers and encoding

Answer (score 0):

I think that i found the problem. 
I manage to get access to the webservice code and I discovered that the file that is used to update the bdd of the webservice is encoded in ANSI.
This file is read using this code :

```
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("vols"), "UTF-8");
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(input);
```

I guess that the problem is here, so i will ask the client to change the encoding of this file but i am not sure that it is the only reason for my problem.

thanks for your help guys.